# Camera2 API HDR+ Auto

Tags: android, android-camera2

Does anyone know of documentation available for implementing HDR+ Auto with the Camera2 API? I have not been able to find any examples where this is used.

Open Camera uses HDR, but not HDR+ Auto.

Answer (score 3):

HDR+ Auto is not part of the camera2 API; it's built on top of the camera2 within the Google Camera App.

You can read about the HDR+ algorithm itself [here](https://research.googleblog.com/2014/10/hdr-low-light-and-high-dynamic-range.html).
The 'Auto' part means that the camera app decides when to use HDR+ and when to take a regular picture, so that it's always fast.

In principle, nothing stops you from building an equivalent image processing algorithm into your own app, but that is admittedly not at all easy.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this ever since I found out that the ported hdr+ app doesn't work on my favorite custom ROM. You can find the original paper [here](http://www.hdrplusdata.org/). I came to know of it from the "Resources" section of [this](https://github.com/timothybrooks/hdr-plus/) implementation.

APKs of many ported versions of the Google Camera (hdr+) are available on XDA forums, and I found a Github project for one such version [here](https://github.com/amirzaidi/gcam).